# How to format drive without losing grub?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, hard-disk

I've got this filesystem layout:

```
$ df -h | sort
/dev/sda1        19G   44M   18G   1% /home/old_root
/dev/sda2       440G   71M  418G   1% /home/old_backup
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  1.2T  604G  66% /home
/dev/sdc2        23G  7.6G   15G  35% /
/dev/sdc5       887G  101G  741G  12% /home/backup
```

I'd like to remove all the partitions on sda, including those which are not mounted, and format the drive with a single large partition. **However, grub is on that drive.** How can I remove all the partitions and create one large partition without endangering grub?

I'm not against the idea of moving grub to another partition, but my BIOS makes that a pain because there is no way to ensure which drive will get which sdX designation. I'm currently running Kubuntu 14.04, this is what `lshw` reports about the motherboard and BIOS:

```
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: H81M-K
   vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
   physical id: 0
   version: Rev X.0x
   serial: 140322933907381
   slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
      physical id: 0
      version: 0803
      date: 04/15/2014
      size: 64KiB
      capacity: 8128KiB
      capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
```

Comment: As long as you do not create a new disklabel and only remove and create partitions, you should be save.